# $(window).load() is getting called infinite times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I've a simple approach for performing a click event on a button using js/jquery

```
<c:if test="${param.error eq true}">    
    <button id="btn-id" style="visibility = hidden;">Do Click Me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">                         
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#btn-id").trigger("click");
        });
     </script>      
</c:if>
```

with all this when I submit the form and *error* parameter comes true I get loop of calls on

```
$("#btn-id").trigger("click");
```

how can I restrict click to one time only?

Comment: Try to write a code snippet to reproduce it...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var buttonClicked = false;                
    $(window).load(function() {
    if(!buttonClicked){
        $("#btn-id").trigger("click");
     buttonClicked = true;
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hmmmm but in which way it differs from OP code? Yes, there is a flag which **should not be necessary** and it may hide a bug somewhere else. Obviously OP code isn't the _real_ one. For code you/we have flag is unnecessary (at best).